# django-tenants: redirecting to tenant url after login raises "NoReverseMatch: 'demo.localhost' is not a registered namespace"

Tags: python, django

I don't seem to find a way to solve an error happening at the user authentication.

User needs to login at the public website level let's say `localhost/login` and when he/she is authenticated, I need the user to be redirected in the corresponding sub domain, for example `demo.localhost`. This is not working for me so far, even after checking some posts about the subject.

Here is the views.py in `customers.views` where user log in:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request,data=request.POST)
        print("form login view")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("checkpoint")
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            user = form.get_user()
            schema_name = user.schema_name

            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                url = reverse(schema_name + '.localhost:8000/mydashboard/')
                print("url")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        print("not working")
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
                }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

here is what urls in the core folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
    path('mydashboard/', include('mydashboard.urls',namespace="mydashboard")),
    
]
```

and I have added `app_name = 'mydashboard'` in `mydashboard.urls`

Here is the traceback of the error I keep getting:

```
Internal Server Error: /registration/loginUser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 71, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
KeyError: 'demo.localhost'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/simulation_application/customers/views.py", line 65, in login_view
    url = reverse(schema_name + '.localhost:8000/mydashboard/')
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 82, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'demo.localhost' is not a registered namespace
```

UPDATE:
Remove the `reverse` and included `request.scheme` in the url.

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request,data=request.POST)
        print("form login view")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("checkpoint")
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            user = form.get_user()
            schema_name = user.schema_name

            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print(request.scheme)
                url = request.scheme + '://' + schema_name + '.localhost:8000/mydashboard/'
                print("url",url)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        print("not working")
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
                }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

this is still working and output the following error:

```
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py, line 32, in _wrapped_view
            return redirect_to_login( …
Local vars
/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py, line 190, in redirect_to_login
    return HttpResponseRedirect(urlunparse(login_url_parts)) …
Local vars
/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/http/response.py, line 507, in __init__
            raise DisallowedRedirect("Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol '%s'" % parsed.scheme) …
Local vars

Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'localhost'
Bad Request: /mydashboard/simulations_list
HTTP GET /mydashboard/simulations_list 400 [0.09, 127.0.0.1:50218]
```

This is strange because the requested url is perfectly working url, registered and accessible without a problem before trying to redirect to it after the login

EDIT #2:

Found out that the above code works when the target url does not require `login required`

```
# this does not work 
@login_required
def simulationslistView(request,):
     return render(request, 'simulations_list.html')

# this works
def simulationslistView(request,):
     return render(request, 'simulations_list.html')
```

I am obviously make sure that the app is secured and can only be accessed by logged in users. Is there a work around to make sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

`reverse` is an internal django utility to go from "app name" + ':' + "url friendly name" to "real url". In your example, you're already providing the "real url".

Quit while you're ahead and just do:

```
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                url = request.scheme + '://' + schema_name + '.localhost:8000/mydashboard/'
                print("url")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

- Notice no `reverse`
- Notice the adding of the URL scheme (http/https determined by how the request was originally made)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! The error indeed went way but now it output "Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'localhost'", which is why I tried working with ```reverse```

Comment: @Murcielago https://github.com/django/django/blob/b1005c0e4029c23f4e718ce0a7afdfa926c095de/django/http/response.py#L576

Looks like the issue might be the `request.scheme + '://'` check the URL and make sure its valid. "Should" look something like [http/https] `"http://somename.localhost:8000/mydashboard"` if it doesn't paste it here.

Comment: I think you omitted my addition of `request.scheme + '://' +` in your URL. It is VERY required. Not to be confused with your `schema_name` that is also required.. it's all required :P

Comment: I wish I omitted lol, I have it in place and output the same thing, and the url seems just fine too: ```http://demo.localhost:8000/mydashboard/simulations_list``` and is pointing a working template```

Comment: And you're getting what error from `HttpResponseRedirect`? Can you paste it in your main question? [the exception]

Comment: I've been trying to debug this, makes no sense, https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/http/response.py#L499-L504 you're going to have to debug this at the django level, from what ive been able to see, it should work, unless something else is going terrible wrong: `urlparse(str('http://demo.localhost:8000/mydashboard/simulations_list')).scheme == 'http'`

Comment: Thank you for effort Javier! I think I just found out what's up. LOGIN_URL in ```settings.py``` was:```localhost:8000/registration/loginUser'``` (forgot the http:// part) which was causing the unsafe url error. BUT it showed me a bigger issue being that a user needs to be register inside of a specific db schema auth table to be able to be logged in. So pretty much the login page would always redirect to the same login page no matter what. No clue how to get it to work so I'll rest to a simpler auth system unfortunately. Thanks for your help anyways!